# How can I get material from a parent actor in Unreal Engine 5 using blueprints?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to create an Actor blueprint that I can assign to any actor that will get material from parent and store it into a variable. Now I know about the node "Get Material", but when i want to use it with "Get Owner", "Get Parent Attached", etc. None of this way works.
I want to assign this blueprint on multiple meshes in the level, but I don't know how to achieve the "get material" stuff. :(
Please help.

I've created the actor blueprint, I've tried even:

Get parent component > Cast to mesh component > get material > set material variable.

But it says it will always fail the cast.